# D3 - Hiding multiple nodes using style opacity, selected.style is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Based on S is for Search from http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/, I am trying to add a specific filter to some nodes.

The function searchNode() is working properly with the following code:

```
function searchNode() {
        //find the node
        var selectedVal = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node");
        if (selectedVal == "none") {
            node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
        } else {
            var selected = node.filter(function (d, i) {
                return d.label != selectedVal;
            });
            selected.style("opacity", "0");
            var link = svg.selectAll(".edge")
            link.style("opacity", "0");
            d3.selectAll(".node, .edge").transition()
                    .duration(5000)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to adept this snippet to a very specific filter (nodes with no primarykeys and no foreignkeys), I am getting syntax errors which don't appear in the searchNode() function.

```
function filterViews(){
        var node = d3.selectAll(".node").data();
        var selected = node.filter(function(d, i){
            return d.primaryKey === undefined && d.foreignKeys.length === 0;
        })
        // selected is the array of nodes that I do NOT want to show
        console.log(selected);

        // I want to hide them using opacity..selected.style is not a function
        selected.style("opacity", "0");

        // Same error.
        selected.forEach(function(d){
            d.style("opacity", "0");
        })

        // Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined
        selected.forEach(function () {
            d3.select(this).style("opacity", "0");
        });


    }
```

**Question: How do I apply opacity style to the selected nodes?**

**Reproduce:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Bx0qe8DNEsnFgLhkxbfS?p=preview scroll all the way down to line 510

Comment: I'm going to guess that the most likely issue is that you aren't working with d3 objects when you attempt to use `.style`. Try something like `selected.each(function () { d3.select(this).style("opacity", "0"); });` and see if that works. If not then it may be because your `node` selection differs from the original code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The suggested fix does not seem to work. It gives a `Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined` error. 

The nodes "selected" are 7 nodes just defined like all the other nodes. As such I am not quite sure what you mean with the node selection differs from the original code. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The original code uses `svg.selectAll(".node");`, while yours uses `d3.selectAll(".node").data();`, note the extra `data()` function. Not sure if this would have an effect on things, or if it is intended.

Comment: Thats it! The combination of the selection and the filter and removing the data() element filters the nodes how I want. Thanks alot. Perhaps you could post the working snippet and I can accept it as answer?

`function filterViews(){
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node");
        var selected = node.filter(function(d, i){
            return d.primaryKey === undefined && d.foreignKeys.length === 0;
        })

selected.style("opacity", "0");`